# Xpath get element within the current context

Tags: xpath

Are there any differences between

```
xpath('./element')
```

and

```
xpath('element')
```

when we want to get the current context?

And could you please advise what is it better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xpath('element')` > selects all nodes with the name `element`

`xpath('./element')` > selects from the current node, all nodes with the name `element` that are first child

Example of usage for better understanding:

Select `A` element that has `B` element anywhere in it:  `A[.//B]`
Select `A` element that has `B` element as first child: `A[./B]`

From what I understand, you shouldn't use `.` if you are not in a specific element and you want to search in that element.