# Iterate in xpath DOM nodes in browser Console ("$x(…)") to work wiht

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, xpath

It's my first question here and I'm from Argentina, so I'm going to try to be accurate.
I have this part of a DOM tree:

```
<div class="c-performance">
    <div class="c-performance__title">
        <h1>Desempeño</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="c-tela">
    <div class="c-tela__title">
        <h1>Pantalla</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="c-conectividade">
    <div class="c-conectividade__title">Conectividad</div>
</div>
```

In the console in browser (in this case Firefox) I'm looking to iterate the "divs" nodes and be able to do another thing (it does not matter now). So, I did this:

```
var a = $x('//div[contains(@class,"__title")]');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var e = a[i]......('h1');
    console.log(e);
}
```

In the "....." what do I have to put? $x? .$x? $? Everything gives me an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a document about `$x` in this firefox page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers#$x

Base on that page, the full command is:  `$x(xpath, element, resultType)`

So you can use `a[i]` as element in that command:

```
var a = $x('//div[contains(@class,"__title")]');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var e = $x('./h1',a[i]);
    console.log(e);
}
```

Note that we use `./h1` to select current node instead of `//h1` for whole document.
More information about this can be related in this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298762